# How to update UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have one UIImageView class "Sticker". I am creating different object of this class in another class to add Stickers.

```
Sticker  *stick = [[Sticker alloc]initWithFrame:[self calculateSize:img]];
stick.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[stick update:img];
//stick.image = img;
[imageView addSubview:stick];
[stick release];
```

Where imageView is the UIImageView of Parent class, on this I am adding Stickers.
But  when I want to edit that Sticker image , I am getting the image from Sticker ImageView by using global UIImage but after editing , the edited image is not updating to the old Sticker imageView.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem????

Answer (score 0):

Add all Stickers objects in array with tags and modify stickers with accessing via Tags of Image View.